# How do I merge accounts in 'Contacts'

Tags: contacts

When I open Contacts on my MacBook I have many confusing/irritating instances where there are two contacts with the same name and with more or less the same information - one is on my Mac the other is in the iCloud.

Can I merge the accounts (NOT the individual contacts)?  And... are there any reasons why I shouldn't.

Comment: If you can clarify? You have only one "account" which is your AppleID. On your phone go to "Settings > AppleID (top selection) >iCloud > Apps Using iCloud." Check and see if contacts is on. Similar thing on your Mac. If iCloud for contacts is on on both places iCloud will combine the contacts list, including duplicates. I believe there are freeware programs that can help you work on duplicate contacts

Comment: @SteveChambers - thanks for your suggestion.  Contacts is 'on' on both my phone and my Macbook.  I have two 'accounts' within 'Contacts' - my personal email and my icloud email.  Most of my contacts are listed twice when I scroll through and I want them to appear just once.  The information in the two versions is the same.